# Solving for gluon propagator in axial gauge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-chromodynamics, greens-functions, propagator, gauge

I know the two-point function is given by:

$$
\Gamma^{A_\mu^a A_\nu^b}(p) = -i \delta^{ab} (g_{\mu \nu} p^2 - p_\mu p_\nu + \frac{1}{\zeta}n^\mu n^\nu)
$$

and I am looking to solve for the inverse of this $I_{\nu \rho}$:

$$
(g_{\mu \nu} p^2 - p_\mu p_\nu + \frac{1}{\zeta}n^\mu n^\nu)I_{\nu \rho} = g^\mu_\rho
$$

with $I = Ag_{\nu \rho} + Bp_\nu p_\rho + C n_\nu n_\rho + D(p_\nu n_\rho + n_\nu p_\rho)$

But I'm not sure where I am going wrong when finding the coefficients $A,B,C,D$. For example, the correct answer for $A$ is:

$$
A = \frac{1}{p^2}
$$

but when I expand out, I get this for the terms with $A$:

$$
Ag_\rho^\mu(p^2 - p^2 + \frac{1}{\zeta}n^2) + \ldots
$$

so not sure how to solve for A to get the correct answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting the ansatz $$I^{\nu \rho}=A \eta^{\nu \rho}+Bp^\nu p^\rho+Cn^\nu n^\rho+D(p^\nu n^\rho+n^\nu p^\rho)   $$ into   $$(\eta_{\mu \nu}-p_\mu p_\nu +n_\mu n_\nu/\xi)I^{\nu\rho}=\delta_\mu^{\,\rho}, $$ one finds the equations $$\begin{align}A p^2 &=1, \\   -A-D \, p\cdot n &=0, \\ C \, p^2+A/\xi +n^2 C/\xi+D \, n\cdot p /\xi &=0, \\ -C \, p\cdot n &=0, \\ D \, p^2+B \, n\cdot p /\xi+D \, n^2/\xi &=0, \end{align}$$ by comparing the coefficients of $\delta_\mu^{\, \rho}$, $p_\mu p^\rho$, $n_\mu n^\rho$, $p_\mu n^\rho$ and $n_\mu p^\rho$. The solution is given by $$A=1/p^2, \quad B=(\xi p^2+n^2)/(p^2(n\cdot p)^2), \quad C=0, \quad D=-1/(p^2 \, n\cdot p ),    $$such that $$I_{\mu \nu}=\frac{1}{p^2}\left[\eta_{\mu \nu}+\frac{\xi p^2+n^2}{(n\cdot p)^2} p_\mu p_\nu -\frac{p_\mu n_\nu+n_\mu p_\nu}{p\cdot n}  \right].$$

Comment: Greatly appreciated!